An algorithm of Max-Cut
Suppose we have an $\alpha$-approximation algorithm $A$ for the Max-Cut problem. On a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ uniformly weighted edges, the runtime of $A$ is $f(n,m/n)$, where $f$ is a function where $f(n,C)\in \mathrm{poly}(n)$ for all constants $C\geq 0$.
Show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a (possibility randomized) poly-time algorithm achiecing $(\alpha-\epsilon)$-approximation for all graph.
I am puzzled that how to converted the time complexity to the all graphs.
